# How To create Function for select inner text of html tag in SQL

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this HTML source:

```
<div id="naver">
    <ul id="naverlist">
        <li class="overbrand" class="navhome"><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/acer-laptop-power-adapters.htm">Acer</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/asus-laptop-power-adapters.htm">ASUS</a></li>
        <li class="navspecial"><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/contact.htm" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to create function for select inner text of `<li>` elements with `<a>` and return URL and brand laptop.

Example:

```
brandname   url
acer        laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/acer-laptop-power-adapters.htm
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done if you send this HTML (as XML) into function and this function will return table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.htmltotable (   
    @html xml
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT  t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as Brand,
            t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
    FROM @html.nodes('/div/ul/li/a') as t(v)
)
GO
```

**But here comes a problem:**

You have `class="overbrand" class="navhome"` in first `<li>`. It will throw error `duplicate attribute` on a moment when you convert your text to XML. So you need to do something with your HTML first.

F.e. if this:

```
<li class="overbrand" class="navhome"><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz">HOME</a></li>
```

is a standard for all pages you can use [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(max),
        @replacement nvarchar(max) = ' class="overbrand" class="navhome"'

SELECT @x = N'
<div id="naver">
    <ul id="naverlist">
        <li class="overbrand" class="navhome"><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/acer-laptop-power-adapters.htm">Acer</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/asus-laptop-power-adapters.htm">ASUS</a></li>
        <li class="navspecial"><a href="http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/contact.htm" target="_blank">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>'

SELECT @x = REPLACE(@x,@replacement,'')

SELECT *
FROM dbo.htmltotable(@x)
```

Output:

```
Brand       URL
HOME        http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz
Acer        http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/acer-laptop-power-adapters.htm
ASUS        http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/asus-laptop-power-adapters.htm
Contact Us  http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/contact.htm
```

Comment: very good.thanks for answer,please help me .1.maybe get source code with sql?.2.parse url of acer and return url and model of acer. please visit site. 3-Home and contact us dont get . thanks and very thanks

Comment: 1 and 2 It is completely another question and it is much better done with another tools like c# or php. 3. To get rid of them you can add WHERE [URL] NOT IN ('HOME','Contact Us'). Or even in function to filter them.

Comment: why t ? why v? why '.'? why ' @href'?thanks for answer

Comment: In 'nodes' we pass the full pat to nodes we need. You can use any other letters instead of t(v)... g(s) or h(j) or whatever, it is an alias so we can refer to that part ast t.v. Value brings the value of node or attribute we need. Dot brings innertext, '@somename' brings the value of attribute. F.e. for brand name is used dot, because it is an inner text of a tag and for link url is used '@href' attribute, because the value is inside a tag in href attribute.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. So for the contents of the text from dot and for the address of the page@href we use. is The difference between S and v?(T(v) T(s)) وWhen I wanted to change V TO S, error.

Comment: if you change `t(v)` to `t(s)` you need to change `t.v.value` to `t.s.value` have you done it?

Comment: To make it clear: `nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)` so `t` is a table name, `v` is a column name, then we can use `t.v.(something)` to work with data (exist, value, query, modify).

Comment: Is it possible that this was part of the function or variable???@replacement nvarchar(max) = ' class="overbrand" class="navhome"'

Comment: please view source page acer brand, this source code very big,Can I use this function to do?

Comment: No, if you want this you should use stored procedure. The limits of xml/nvarchar(max) is 2 GB in SQL Server so it should store this html.

Comment: help me my friend

Comment: With what? Once more - `@replacement` could be used in stored procedure, not in function. And on second one: yes it will parse your page without a problem - have you seen web-pages with size of even 1 GB?

Comment: 1.with c# or sql.----2. for @replacement SP example? 3.When I am out of that function to the source page`Acer(url:http://www.laptop-power-adapters.co.nz/acer-laptop-power-adapters.htm) I fail . Please test is possible? 4. I am really sorry for my questions.

Comment: There is plenty of manuals on creating SP like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure).

Comment: I can use the t.v.value(variable)instead of t.v.value(`ul/li`)for mobility?

Comment: What variable? If you are about `@href` in that case `@` is a message to XQuery that it needs to return value of attribute `href`

Comment: {{{{ ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_htmltotable] 
(@html   xml , @x1 nvarchar(max))

AS
BEGIN

SELECT    t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as Brand,
                  t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
  FROM     @html.nodes('li/a') as t(v)
END}}}}    use the @html.nodes('li/a') ----> @html.nodes(@tag)-----> @tag=li/a?

Comment: How do you think, is it hard to read some code posted as comment? You have function that returns table with data you need, now you can create a stored proc to pass html as text (nvarchar(max)), then replace some values like below than pass it to function.

Comment: The code from second part of my answer could be pasted right in SP.

Comment: for this code html :( <a href="/Acer/AcerNote/330-Laptop-Battery.aspx?prodid=1608&modelid=578551&seriesid=33&manid=12&catid=3" class="linkbutton green" style="width: 110px;" ></a> ) error : XML parsing: line 1, character 70, semicolon expected

Comment: Thanks gofr1 for help me.

Comment: Well, & symbol is special in xml, you need to replace & with &amp;

Comment: help for above code? please q or function for replace in this example.thanks

Comment: It is simple replace like with classes in my answer. What do you use to obtain html page code?

Comment: SET @HTML = STUFF(@html, CHARINDEX('&', @html), 1,'&amp;')????but while this function , loop not end.

Comment: i want to @href  t.v.value(@href but error semicolon

Comment: Set @html=replace(@html,'&','&amp;')

Comment: SELECT  t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as Brand,
             t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
     FROM @htmlXML.nodes('li/a') as t(v)

Comment: Thank u gofr1. gofr 1 .When I want import konam xml doc for @html و When the servant of @x is such, that error: var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
    "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
    scJsHost+
    "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>") ,

Comment: @MohsenNz What is that?? Look, you need to use PHP or C# to get a clear xml to send it to SQL Server. SQL Server is NOT A TOOL TO manipulate with html/css/js files. Its purpose is to store and retrieve data.

Comment: use c# . @gofr1 thanks for help but if in the line (<a href="/Acer/AcerNote/330-Laptop-Battery.aspx?prodid=1608&mod‌​elid=578551&seriesid‌​=33&manid=12&catid=3‌​" class="linkbutton green" style="width: 110px;" ></a>)  there & and && or &amp; then with replace & to &amp; then in line possible there &amp; to &amp;amp;, ???

Comment: No, & -> &amp; &&-> &amp;&amp;

Comment: You are asking something weird, I don't understand. You try to say that it is some pages that has both & and &amp; on same page and this replacement make second values invalid? Or what?

Comment: this example : <a href="asasdasd&asdsa&amp;dsd.html > asas</a> if i want replace & with &amp; then output is <a href="asasdasd&amp;asdsa&amp;amp;dsd.html > asas</a> , ok?

Comment: You are a developer? What is the most obvious answer to your question? You can use whatever you want number of replaces. It is a 38 comments on this post, it is not funny. Start DEVELOPING if you work with xml and SQL - learn this stuff. And stop asking questions like what to do if you got &amp; already, replace it with & then replace & with &amp;.

Comment: sorry and thanks my friend. my problem is start when replace drop in loop.thanks

Comment: In this example I meant was that when we replace these may show others the right wrong

Comment: Sorry, man, I just don't like this long conversations about stuff that could be googled.